# How to change transparency in SVG style-sheet for Solidworks

Tags: css, svg, solidworks

[Stylesheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSgcB.png)

So I'm trying to create a style in Solidworks that would make the text it is applied to transparent. The stylesheet seems to be similar to CSS but it is not quite the same. Below is an example of some of the styles I'm able to reference from the default stylesheet.

STYLE_KEY ELLIPSE
STYLE_FILL none
STYLE_STROKECOLOR black
STYLE_STROKEWIDTH 0.2%
STYLE_FONTSIZE 12
STYLE_FONTFAMILY helvetica
STYLE_FONTSTYLE normal
STYLE_FONTWEIGHT normal
STYLE_BASELINESHIFT 0
STYLE_TEXTDECORATION 0

STYLE_KEY ELLIPTICALARC
STYLE_FILL none
STYLE_STROKECOLOR black
STYLE_STROKEWIDTH 0.2%
STYLE_FONTSIZE 12
STYLE_FONTFAMILY helvetica
STYLE_FONTSTYLE normal
STYLE_FONTWEIGHT normal
STYLE_BASELINESHIFT 0
STYLE_TEXTDECORATION 0

STYLE_KEY WHITE
STYLE_FILL none
STYLE_STROKECOLOR white
STYLE_STROKEWIDTH 0.2%
STYLE_FONTSIZE 12
STYLE_FONTFAMILY helvetica
STYLE_FONTSTYLE normal
STYLE_FONTWEIGHT normal
STYLE_BASELINESHIFT 0
STYLE_TEXTDECORATION 0
STYLE_PRIORITY 2

Just wanted to know if anyone has seen this format before and if they knew how to add a line to change the opacity. I tried adding "STYLE_OPACITY .5","STYLE_OPACITY 5" "STYLE_OPACITY .5%" etc and nothing has worked. Any insight would be appreciated.